# MATLAB string handling

Tags: string, matlab

I want to calculate the frequency of each word in a string. For that I need to turn string into an array (matrix) of words.

For example take `"Hello world, can I ask you on a date?"` and turn it into

```
['Hello' 'world,' 'can' 'I' 'ask' 'you' 'on' 'a' 'date?']
```

Then I can go over each entry and count every appearance of a particular word.

Is there a way to make an array (matrix) of words in MATLAB, instead of array of just chars?

Comment: Just fyi in Matlab what you ask for is called a "cell of strings" and is written as: `{'Hello' 'world,' 'can' 'I' 'ask' 'you' 'on' 'a' 'date?'}`. Also I think yuk's solution would be more suited as it will return 'date' instead of 'date?'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little simpler `regexp`:

```
words = regexp(s,'\w+','match');
```

`\w` here means any symbol that can appear in words (including underscore).

Notice that the last question mark will not be included. Do you need it for counting words actually?

Comment: what does 'match' argument mean in this case?

Comment: By default regexp returns positions of matched strings. So this parameter is to return matches.

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions

```
s = 'Hello world, can I ask you on a date?'
slist = regexp(s, '[^ ]*', 'match')
```

yield

```
slist = 

'Hello'    'world,'    'can'    'I'    'ask'    'you'    'on'    'a'    'date?'
```

Comment: Can you go in details of what '([^ \ ][^\ ]*)' means?

Comment: Now that I think about it, regexp(s, '([^ \ ][^\ ]*)', 'match'), is unnecessarily complicated. regexp(s, '[^ ]*', 'match') does what you want. The regular expression [^ ]* matches any number of characters that are not a space and the matlab function regexp returns these matches as a cell array. Response is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is like this:

```
s = cell(java.lang.String('Hello world, can I ask you on a date?').split('[^\w]+'));
```

I.e. by creating a Java String object and using its methods to do the work, then converting back to a cell array of strings. Not necessarily the best way to do a job this simple, but Java has a rich library of string handling methods & classes that can come in handy.

Matlab's ability to switch into Java at the drop of a hat can come in handy sometimes - for example, when parsing & writing XML.